# Counting the numbers between 1 and N (inclusive) where the i-th bit is set

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I want to count how many integers between 1 and *N* have their *i*th bit set. For example, if *N* = 10 and *i* = 0, then the result should be 5 (because 1 = 0001<sub>2</sub>, 3 = 0011<sub>2</sub>, 5 = 0101<sub>2</sub>, 7 = 0111<sub>2</sub>, and 9 = 1001<sub>2</sub> each have a 1 at bit 0).

The naive linear-time solution is to iterate from 1 to *N* and, for each number, see if it has its *i*th bit set.

A slightly better approach would be that because for a known power of 2 (say 2<sup>*x*</sup>), 2<sup>*x*−1</sup> numbers will have their *i*th bit set till the number 2<sup>*x*</sup> − 1, where 0 ≤ i < x. So calculate all the numbers with their *i*th bit set starting from (*N* − 2<sup>*x*</sup>), where *N* is the number till we seek to find all the numbers with their *i*th bit set and 2<sup>*x*</sup> is the nearest power of 2 for the number *N*. This approach decreases the number of iterations but is still a linear-time solution and can in some cases be very useless for higher numbers.

Is there a constant-time solution?

Comment: There is, although it will take *log2(n)*, since as *N* grows large, the number of bits of *N* need to be taken into account.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please share the algorithm as log(n) is always an improvement over a linear time solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first take a look at an example. If we set `n=10`, and we look at the second bit, so `k=1` from the right, we see:

```
0000    0
0001    0
0010    1
0011    2
0100    2
0101    2
0110    3
0111    4
----
1000    4
1001    4
1010    5
```

We here see that there are *⌊N/2<sup>k+1</sup>⌋* full *round trips* of the *k*-th bit, and each such round trip results in *2<sup>k</sup>* set bits. We grouped these entries before the horizontal bar.

Furthermore there are then still *N + 1 - 2<sup>k+1</sup>×⌊N/2<sup>k+1</sup>⌋* entries *under* the horizontal bar. We know for sure that this is *less* than *2<sup>k</sup>*, since otherwise *⌊N/2<sup>k</sup>⌋* would be one higher. The first *2<sup>k-1</sup>* entries have `0` as selected bit, whereas the remaining bits (at most *2<sup>k-1</sup>* entries) have `1` as selected bit.

We can thus construct the following algorithm in Haskell:

```
countBit k n = c1 +  max 0 (n + 1 - c0 - sk)
    where sk = shiftL 1 k
          c1 = shiftL (shiftR n (k+1)) k
          c0 = shiftL c1 1
```

For example for `k=1`, we obtain the following counts:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> map (countBit 0) [0..32]
[0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16]
Prelude Data.Bits> map (countBit 1) [0..32]
[0,0,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,13,14,14,14,15,16,16]
Prelude Data.Bits> map (countBit 2) [0..32]
[0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,10,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,14,15,16,16]
Prelude Data.Bits> map (countBit 3) [0..32]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,16]
Prelude Data.Bits> map (countBit 4) [0..32]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,16]
```

So for `n=10` and `k=1`, we get the expected:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> countBit 0 10
5
Prelude Data.Bits> countBit 1 10
5
```

Or we can count the number of set bits with column `k=3` for numbers from `0` to `12345` (inclusive) with:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> countBit 3 12345
6170
```

or for `k=15` and `n=12'345'678'901'234'567'890`

```
Prelude Data.Bits> countBit 15 12345678901234567890
6172839450617282560
```

and for `n=123'456'789'012'345'678'901'234'567'890`:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> countBit 15 123456789012345678901234567890
61728394506172839450617282560
```

We here perform some bitshifts and subtractions, for large numbers, these can be done in *O(log N)* time (with *N* the value of the upperbound).

Comment: "The first 2^(k-1) entries have 0 as selected bit, whereas the remaining bits (at most 2^(k-1) entries) have 1 as selected bit." What do you mean by this?

Comment: @PiyushRanjan: take a look at the items under the horizontal bar, with `k=2` the first `2^k-1=2` elements will be `0` for that bit, and the remaining `2` bits will be one, of course we are not interested in all these bits per se.